# GitHub NIFTI-Reader-JS tests not working: "Uncaught ReferenceError: nifti is not defined"

Tags: javascript, html, github, referenceerror, nifti

When I clone the [NIFTI-Reader-JS repository](https://github.com/rii-mango/NIFTI-Reader-JS) to my local machine and run the [canvas.html](https://github.com/rii-mango/NIFTI-Reader-JS/blob/master/tests/canvas.html) or the [browser.html](https://github.com/rii-mango/NIFTI-Reader-JS/blob/master/tests/browser.html) test files I get an `Uncaught ReferenceError: nifti is not defined` when I choose a file to open. This happens with the test data provided as well as with other NIfTI data. The full error is shown below and is raised in both the newest versions of Google Chrome and Micosoft Edge. Since I'm new to JavaScript I suspect some simple issue to be the problem but I couldn't figure out how to get the test files working.

The full error (when using the [canvas.html](https://github.com/rii-mango/NIFTI-Reader-JS/blob/master/tests/canvas.html) test file):

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: nifti is not defined
    at readNIFTI (canvas.html:18:13)
    at reader.onloadend (canvas.html:140:21)
readNIFTI @ canvas.html:18
reader.onloadend @ canvas.html:140
FileReader (async)
readFile @ canvas.html:144
handleFileSelect @ canvas.html:149
```

### What I tried so far

Since the test should work without modifications I did not expect such error. Nevertheless, I tried changing the source paths and source files so that they were all in the same directory but that didn't work. In addition, I tried to import the `nifti` variable from the source files using the following at the top of the second `<script>` tag in [canvas.html](https://github.com/rii-mango/NIFTI-Reader-JS/blob/master/tests/canvas.html):

- `import {nifti} from '../release/current/nifti-reader.js';`
- `import nifti from '../release/current/nifti-reader.js';`
- `import * as nifti from '../release/current/nifti-reader.js';`
- `nifti = require('../release/current/nifti-reader.js');` which resulted in an `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` and the `Uncaught ReferenceError: nifti is not defined`

I tried this with the current directory structure and all files in the same directory. Unfortunately, both didn't resolve the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Use version 0.5.4

The newest version if the [NIfTI Reader JS](https://github.com/rii-mango/NIFTI-Reader-JS) is only compatible with NodeJS and is not compatible with the browser.

[NIfTI Reader JS version 0.5.4](https://github.com/rii-mango/NIFTI-Reader-JS/releases/tag/v0.5.4) is supported in the browser and supports both the NIfTI 1 and 2 format. *This version is the last of the 0.5.x versions.*

Answer (score 0):

Could you try changing line 9 in canvas.html from:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../release/current/nifti-reader.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="module" src="../release/current/nifti-reader.js"></script>
```

and see if it changes anything?

Comment: This isn't much of an answer and would be better left as a comment.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, it did not work as expected. Apparently the [NIfTI Reader JS repository](https://github.com/rii-mango/NIFTI-Reader-JS) is only compatible with NodeJS and fails in the browser. I'm currently checking out possibilities (such as the usage of `browserify`) and I will eventually give an update.